# Why my simple view is not working

Tags: backbone.js

I have this JS code:

```
$(function() {

  var LinkView = new Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.model.get('text'));
    }
  });

  var Link = Backbone.Model.extend({
    text: 'message',

    say: function() {
      console.log(this.text);
    }
  });

  var l = new Link();
  l.say();

  var v = new LinkView({model : l, el : 'body'});
  v.render();
});
```

I am waiting to get 'message' on the browser, but get the error `TypeError: r.apply is not a function` in the console.  Why and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Do you really have `var LinkView = new Backbone.View.extend({...})` rather than `var LinkView = Backbone.View.extend({...})`?

Comment: Also, `text` is a JavaScript property in `Link`, not a Backbone attribute so `this.model.get('text')` won't work. You'd want to `new Link({ text: 'message' })` if you wanted an attribute that you could `get`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me. As I see I can use `this.$el.html(this.model.text);` too

Comment: You can but Backbone won't know anything about the `text` property so there won't be any events when it changes, it won't be part of the server communication for saves and fetches, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste this, `new` was the problem in View, also did slight modification. it works now..

```
$(function() {

 var Link = Backbone.Model.extend({

 defaults : {
     text: 'default message'
  },

  say: function() {
  console.log(this.get('text'));
  }
});

 var LinkView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render : function() {
  this.$el.html(this.model.get('text'));
   }
 });

 var l = new Link({text:'custom text message'});
 l.say();

 var v = new LinkView({model : l, el : 'body'});
 v.render();
});
```